# How do I calculate closed loop gain's deviation?

Tags: loop-gain

I have an exercise in my book that I am trying to solve:

> How large must the magnitude of the loop gain, \$ |A \beta| \$ be in order
>   for the closed loop gain, \$ A_t \$, to deviate less than 0.1% from the
>   asymptotic gain, \$ A_{t \infty} \$ .

Since the amplification is given by:
$$ A_t = A_{t \infty} \frac{-A \beta}{1-A \beta} $$

This means that \$ \frac{A_t}{A_{t \infty}} = 1-0.001 = 0.999\$

By solving the inequality 
$$ 0.999 \leq \frac{-A \beta}{1-A \beta} $$

I get \$ AB \leq -999 \$ and \$ AB > 1 \$.

But for some reason the answer in the book is different from my calculation

**Answer in the book:**
$$ |AB| \geq 999 $$ which is equivalent to $$ -999 < AB < 999 $$

Comment: A loop gain greater than +1 is an oscillator, less than 1 or negative for amplifiers

Comment: @sstobbe Can I then skip the component \$ AB > 1 \$ and just write \$ AB \leq -999 \$ as \$ AB- \geq 999 \$ and then just  \$ |AB| \geq 999 \$?

Comment: You treat an equality like an equals sign you shouldn't have 2 answers for AB

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect too, your saying |AB|>999 is the same as AB being between -999 and 999

Comment: Ideal closed loop gain is 1/B

Comment: @sstobbe I get two solutions for that inequality: www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.999+\leq+%28-x%29%2F%281-x%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume loop gain \$k=A\beta\$. Then:

$$\begin{align*}
A_{CL}&=\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot\frac{k}{1+k}
\end{align*}$$

\$\frac{1}{\beta}\$ is the ideal gain as \$A_{OL}\rightarrow \infty\$, so this means that the second factor would ideally be exactly 1. The error term is then the difference between the second factor and 1:

$$\begin{align*}
\bigg|1-\frac{k}{1+k}\bigg| \le 0.001\\\\
\bigg|\frac{1}{1+k}\bigg| \le 0.001\\\\
\big|1+k\big| \ge 1000\\\\
\big|k\big| \ge 999\\\\
\big|A\beta\big| \ge 999\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! this was what I was looking for!

Comment: With the notation from my problem \$ A_{CL} = A_t \$, \$ A_{t \infty} = \frac{1}{B_{FB}} \$ and \$ k = -A \beta \$.

Comment: @Clone Yeah. Understood.

Comment: after closer inspection I am not really sure how you went from \$ |1 + k| \geq 1000 \$ to \$ |k| \geq 999 \$ these inequalities does not seem to be equivalent.   www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C1%2Bx%7C+%5Cgeq+1000

Comment: @Clone Yeah, good catch. That was a quick wave of the hand, wasn't it? But we know that \$k\$ is positive. I didn't develop the reason why, but you should be able to go back from the basic negative feedback equation and see why I'm right. So I can neglect the negative direction. I probably could have removed the absolute value signs. If you disagree, let me know and I'll expand things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between inverting or non- inverting loop gain types, thus the result is ~abs(x).

that's all

Comment: The loop gain should indeed be negative for this amplifier. Can I then skip the component \$ AB > 1 \$ and just write \$ AB \leq -999 \$ as \$ AB- \geq 999 \$ and then just  \$ |AB| \geq 999 \$?

Comment: i agree...........